# Banno Messaging - SkipInbox and DeepLink

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

I am testing the POST method to send our users Alerts via the Admin API page linked below and I have two questions.

First, what is the SkipInbox setting supposed to do? From my testing, it makes no impact within Banno or to push notifications. Is the setting meant to skip sending an email notification of the alert?

Second, how is the DeepLink supposed to work? In testing, I do not see a link within the alert or the push notification. Is this also specific to an email notification of the alert?

https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/admin-api/api-reference/v0/alerts/details/#/Send%20Alerts/post_a_mobile_api_v0_institutions__institutionId__users__userId__alert_send_generic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: [Edited] The `skipInbox` request parameter is deprecated and should not be used. The functionality for that parameter is not implemented.

Second: The `deepLink` parameter isn't supported yet in the Banno Online + Banno Mobile (Android / iOS) client apps.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the skipInbox parameter? In my testing I receive a push notification and a red icon on the Messages option alerting me of a new message. This is the case when skipInbox is true and when it is false.

Comment: Hmm, it's entirely possible that we have some sort of _regression_ with the `skipInbox` parameter (or the docs are incomplete). We'll have to ask Engineering for some insight.

Comment: Hi @Jaime, Have you heard back from your engineering team regarding the possible regression of the skipInbox paramter?

Comment: Yes, it is a regression. It's supposed to work as documented, but there is a bug.

Comment: Engineering has deployed a fix where the `skipInbox` parameter should be honored rather than doing the same thing in all situations.

Comment: @Svedly as it turns out, there was some confusion. The recent Engineering fix does not solve the actual problem, which is that the `skipInbox` feature is not _implemented_. We've updated the docs to *deprecate* the `skipInbox` parameter and it should not be used. (You may have to force refresh the page in your browser to see the update.)